# Solve PDE by seperation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following PDE by separation of variables:

$\nabla^2 T=0$

$T(0,y)=300 \\ T(4,y)=600 \\ \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}(x,0)=0 \\ \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}(x,2)=0$

$0\leq x \leq 4$ and $0 \leq y \leq 2$

Now using separation of variables i get $T(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ thus, the following ODE equations: $X''+kX=0$ and $Y''-kY=0$

The general solution for $X$ is:

$X=c_1 cos(\mu x)+c_2sin(\mu x)$.

Now by using the inditial conditions $X(0)=300$ gives $c_1=300$ and for $X(4)=600$ we get $X=300 cos(\mu 4)+c_2sin(\mu 4)=600$. We have that $\mu=\mu_n=\frac{n\pi}{4}$ so we get $X=300 cos(n\pi)+c_2sin(n\pi)=600$
In this case, the sine function is always zero! How should I do in this case??

Answer (score 0):

First, you should separate the inhomogeneous part in $X$ from the main equation. Your $\hat{X} = Ax + B$ satisfies $\hat{X}''=0$ and $B=300, 4A=600$. Then you can solve the homogeneous portion as usual, but remember that only the $T$ portion will contain both $\sin$ and $\cos$, the $X$ component will contain $\sin$ only because of homogeneity.